# I need to override my locale from header when the user already has a stored locale language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, locale, setlocale

```
def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  if r = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] 
    r.scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
  end
end


def set_locale
  I18n.locale =  session[:locale] || extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  session[:locale] = I18n.locale
  if current_user
    current_user.language = session[:locale]
    current_user.save
  end
end
```

So what happens now, if a user is not logged, it detects the header locale like I want it to when you visit the site. And when I select change language it changes the locale like I want. so that is all good.

My issue is when I log out, then log back in it should be the locale that I had previously selected on the site, but it keeps pulling the header locale. I feel something is slightly off with how I am saving the user.language but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when the user logs back in you are overwriting their language preference from the the session:

```
current_user.language = session[:locale]
```

This seems like appropriate logic for a new user who has not chosen their own default locale yet, but not for somebody who already has one set. This will ensure that the user's language does not get overwritten if it has already set:

```
current_user.language ||= session[:locale]
```